# Retrieve 3 rows each time (and a subset of columns) from a matrix in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to apply a loop on a matrix (matrixExample, as described below) to retrieve Columns V1 to V6 on 3 rows each time.

```
matrixExample
      ID      CHR SEGNUM GENOSEG  V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6 
 [1,] "CHAR8" "1" "1"    "102505" "1" "0" "2" "5" "0" "5"
 [2,] "LIMO9" "1" "1"    "012505" "0" "1" "2" "5" "0" "5"
 [3,] "SIM10" "1" "1"    "122505" "1" "2" "2" "5" "0" "5"
 [4,] "CHAR8" "1" "2"    "111520" "1" "1" "1" "5" "2" "0"
 [5,] "LIMO9" "1" "2"    "221520" "2" "2" "1" "5" "2" "0"
 [6,] "SIM10" "1" "2"    "222520" "2" "2" "2" "5" "2" "0"
 [7,] "CHAR8" "1" "3"    "501111" "5" "0" "1" "1" "1" "1"
 [8,] "LIMO9" "1" "3"    "501100" "5" "0" "1" "1" "0" "0"
 [9,] "SIM10" "1" "3"    "502011" "5" "0" "2" "0" "1" "1"
[10,] "CHAR8" "2" "1"    "102505" "1" "0" "2" "5" "0" "5"
[11,] "LIMO9" "2" "1"    "012505" "0" "1" "2" "5" "0" "5"
[12,] "SIM10" "2" "1"    "122505" "1" "2" "2" "5" "0" "5"
[13,] "CHAR8" "2" "2"    "111520" "1" "1" "1" "5" "2" "0"
[14,] "LIMO9" "2" "2"    "221520" "2" "2" "1" "5" "2" "0"
[15,] "SIM10" "2" "2"    "222520" "2" "2" "2" "5" "2" "0"
[16,] "CHAR8" "2" "3"    "501111" "5" "0" "1" "1" "1" "1"
[17,] "LIMO9" "2" "3"    "501100" "5" "0" "1" "1" "0" "0"
[18,] "SIM10" "2" "3"    "502011" "5" "0" "2" "0" "1" "1"
```

As example, from the first 3 rows, I would like to do some matrix calculations using the submatrix:

```
"1" "0" "2" "5" "0" "5"
"0" "1" "2" "5" "0" "5"
"1" "2" "2" "5" "0" "5"
```

After this calculation, I need to go to rows 4 to 6 ...

I tried this code:

```
 for(i in seq(1, dim(exampleDoubleSort)[1], 3))
{
  print(matrixExample[(i:i+2),c(4:10)]) # using print only as an example  
  # do some matrix calculations using the subset matrix
}
```

Its only printing the elements from one row and not for the combination of 3 rows.

If I try out of the loop, I can obtain the expected result.

```
      print(matrixExample[(1:3),c(5:10)])

     V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6 
[1,] "1" "0" "2" "5" "0" "5"
[2,] "0" "1" "2" "5" "0" "5"
[3,] "1" "2" "2" "5" "0" "5"
```

Please, could you give me some idea on how to read 3 rows each time and retrieve a matrix subset for further calculations?
If I have 30 hows, I need to retried 10 matrix as subset and perform 10 calculations ... The calculation will be implemented using function as example.

Thanks in advance!
Cheers!

RV

Comment: Your issue is in the indexing of rows, with the generation of the vector of row indices. Look at the difference in output between `3:3+2` and `3:(3+2)`

Comment: As a side note, you would probably better use a `data.frame` instead of a list since you have values of different classes (character/factor and numeric) but a matrix can only contain 1 class and hence all values are coerced to characters

Comment: Thanks a lot Heroka! Solved the issue! Cheers!

Comment: Thanks docendo discimus! Good tip ...

Comment: Just another option using `split` `lapply(split(data, list(data$CHR, data$SEGNUM)), function(x) as.matrix(x[,-c(1:4)]))` considering the data as a `data.frame`